# Copy formula from a specific sheet and cell and drag it down until specific column last row

Tags: vba, excel

So far I have this code below; counting last cell is working fine but is copy/pasting the wrong data to wrong sheet. Should copy data and use the formula from Sheet "Parsing" cell B2, and its using the main sheet where is the VBA. Looks lile what is missing is to execute the copy/select to "parsing" sheet, but didnt manage to do it.

```
Sub drag_formula_original()

Dim myLastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Parsing")



myLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

.Range("B2").Copy Destination:=.Range("B2:B" & myLastRow)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
End Sub
```

Its solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Can you please check my new code above? Actually now gives an error.

Comment: I updated however now it copies the correct data but to wrong sheet. Must go to "Parsing" instead of the first sheet of workbook. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("B2").Copy
```

The above will grab by default from the Activesheet

you have to tell it what sheet you would like it to pick that range/value from.

```
sheets("Parsing").Range("B2").Copy
```

Edit: Just noticed your With

To actually use a with you need to use a "." e.g. your copy line would look like below

```
.Range("B2").Copy
```

One other thing to note this:

```
Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Is rather inefficient, below would be better. Selecting in general is best to keep away from it is rather slow

```
 Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Paste
```

Or with your with

```
.Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Paste
```

Comment: or since the OP is using a `with` statement they can just use `.Range(..)` as they do with `.Cells` already

Comment: Just noticed that and changed answer slightly :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated however now it copies the correct data but to wrong sheet. Must go to "Parsing" sheet instead of the first sheet of workbook. Anyidea why?

Comment: @chancea if i replace Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Select by Sheets("Parsing").Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Select I get an error. But is that the change you mean?

Comment: @99moorem any idea whats still wrong on my above code? I tried your variations but no luck. The code above is the one that still makes sth but copying to wrong sheet. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gonzalo yes that is the change you need.  What is the error?

Comment: @Gonzalo Get rid of all that and the paste statement.  Just use `.Range("B2").Copy Destination:=.Range("B2:B" & myLastRow)`

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your code and ran it. I changed nothing in your code except for adding "Option Explicit" before your sub. (Just a personal habit)

```
Option Explicit
Sub drag_formula_original()

Dim myLastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Parsing")

myLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B2").Copy
Range("B2:B" & myLastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
End Sub
```

I did, however, use a very simple formula in cell B2.  What I did was have column A go from 1 to 10 and column C go from 11 to 20. Cell B2 was =A2+C2.
After running the code I checked each cell in column B and they each had the correct formula in them, and not a hard-coded value.

A trick I do when I want to do something like this but can't figure out how is I record a macro of me dragging the cell formula down a little ways and then stop the recording and look at the code it made.  From that you should be able to adjust it to do what you want.

When I did that I got this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B15"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B2:B15").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats, right, But i wanted the code to operate in different sheet: "Parsing"